# Android Search Widget in Action Bar

Tags: android, android-actionbar, searchview

I have implemented a search view in the action bar of my app.
When running the search function for the first time, everything runs correctly. But on the second run of the search function the soft-keyboard displays 'Next' instead of 'Go' and this does not run the function.

MainActivity (declation of the searchview in my main activity):

```
// Associate searchable configuration with the SearchView
        SearchManager searchManager =
                (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);

        searchMenuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.search);
        searchView =
                (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(searchMenuItem);
        searchView.setSearchableInfo(
                searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));

        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String s) {
                MenuItemCompat.collapseActionView(searchMenuItem);
                searchView.setQuery("", false);
                searchView.setIconified(true);
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String s) {
                return false;
            }
        });
```

POISearchActivity (searchview calls this method and this method in turn calls a function in the main activity):

```
private void handleIntent(Intent intent) {
        //use the query to search your data somehow
        if (Intent.ACTION_SEARCH.equals(intent.getAction())) {
            String query = intent.getStringExtra(SearchManager.QUERY);
            //use the query to search your data somehow
            String[] searchArray = new String[20];
            searchArray[0] = "name like '%"+query+"%'";
            searchArray[1] = "search";

            MainActivity mainInstance = new MainActivity();
            mainInstance.searchFunction(searchArray);
            finish();
        }

    }
```

The function only runs once and I want to reset everything when the user submits his search?
Any ideas how I can do this.